# NodeJS: Functional Programming - No access to prototype in handover function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I try to write a function, that returns a promise version for some API (AgileCRMManager). The design of the api works pretty similar to request.

But i have some Problems with the handover of the Function. The Function have no access to the prototype of its own. I got following log output:

```
[Function: getContactByEmail]
[Function: getContactByEmail]
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at getContactByEmail (/Users/Tilman/Documents/Programme/NodeJS/async_test/node_modules/agile_crm/agilecrm.js:116:24)
    at /Users/Tilman/Documents/Programme/NodeJS/async_test/routes/portal.js:30:5
    at restPromise (/Users/Tilman/Documents/Programme/NodeJS/async_test/routes/portal.js:29:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Tilman/Documents/Programme/NodeJS/async_test/routes/portal.js:22:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
```

This is the part with getOptions from agile_crm:

```
ContactAPI.prototype.getOptions = function getOptions() {
    this._options = {
        host: this.domain,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(this.email + ':' + this.key).toString('base64'),
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    return this._options;
};
```

This is my Code (if i change restFunction with a.contactAPI.getContactByEmail, it works. But i want to have it for more functions):

```
var AgileCRMManager = require("agile_crm")
var a = new AgileCRMManager("user-domain",
        "api-key",
        "user-mail")

restPromise('ds@umzuege-selisch.de',a.contactAPI.getContactByEmail)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)

function restPromise(data, restFunction) {
  console.log(restFunction);                    // => [Function: getContactByEmail]
  console.log(a.contactAPI.getContactByEmail);  // => [Function: getContactByEmail]
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){
    //a.contactAPI.getContactByEmail(
    restFunction(
      data,
      function(data){
        fulfill(data)
      },
      function(error){
        reject(new Error(error))
      }
    )
  })
}
```

Any Idea how i can hand Over the function and api will still work?

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you're calling getOptions. Since the value of `this` depends on how you call a function (not on how you define it) we can't help you if you don't show how you're calling getOptions

Comment: i do not call getOptions in my code. The function which i use provided by the library [agile_crm](https://github.com/agilecrm/nodejs) calls getOptions. The Code with with the function getOptions is from the file under node_modules/agile_crm wich i require in my code.

Comment: OK. I see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood how `this` works in javascript. Normally I'd vote to close questions like this but this seems to be a specific use case that requires further explanation. For a full explanation of how `this` works I'd suggest reading the answer from this question: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628).

#### The Theory

Now, the problem is that in js the value of `this` depends on how you call a function. If a function is a method, `this` resolves to the object the method belongs to:

```
a.foo = function () { console.log(this) };
a.foo() // should output `a`
```

But if the function is a simple function that is not part of an object then `this` is either the global object (window in browsers) or undefined depending on strict mode. Note that js interprets weather or not a function is a method when you call the function. Not when you define the function. This has interesting consequences:

```
a.foo = function () { console.log(this) };
b = a.foo;
b(); // here b is a simple function because it's not something.b
     // so the output is either the global object or undefined
```

#### The Bug

This is what happens in this line of code:

```
restPromise('ds@umzuege-selisch.de',a.contactAPI.getContactByEmail)
```

You're passing `a.contactAPI.getContactByEmail` as a function reference. Therefore it loses the fact that it's part of `a.contactAPI` and instead becomes a simple function. This fact can be clearly seen by how you call the function:

```
restFunction( //...
```

Note that you're calling `restFunction` which is a function reference to `a.contactAPI.getContactByEmail`. Since it is called simply as `restFunction()` instead of `a.contactAPI.restFunction()` the `this` in the function points to the global object (or undefined depending on strict mode) instead of `a.contactAPI`.

#### Fixes

There are several ways you can fix this.

1. Wrap `a.contactAPI.getContactByEmail` in an anonymous function so you can call it with the proper `this`:

   ```
   restPromise(
     'ds@umzuege-selisch.de',
     function(data,ok,err){
       a.contactAPI.getContactByEmail(data,ok,err);
     }
   )
   ```
2. Use `.bind()`:

   ```
   restPromise(
     'ds@umzuege-selisch.de',
     a.contactAPI.getContactByEmail.bind(a.contactAPI)
   )
   ```
3. Modify `restPromise()` to accept an object instead of a function.